# Dropdown menu elements lose focus on tab

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

My dropdown menu button opens on hover (CSS), but its content is not accessible on the tab.

On button- tab, the dropdown menu opens on next tab press it skips all content of the menu, closes it and continues to go to the next focus elements on the page.

I need to be able to tab through the menu. This from my react component:

```
<div className="dropdown" 
        tabIndex="0"
        role="navigation">
          <button className="dropBtn" tabIndex="0" role="menu" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <i className="hover">Places</i>
          </button>
          <div tabIndex="0" className="dropdown-content">
          <div tabIndex='0' className='filter'>
            <input 
              className='input'
              tabIndex="0"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search your place"
              value={this.props.query}            
              onChange={e => this.props.handleUpdateQuery(e.target.value)}/>
              </div>
             {/* <div className="search-places-results"> */}
             <ul className='listOfPlaces' 
             role="menubar">
              {this.props.filteredPlaces.map((item)=>{
                return <li item={item} 
                tabIndex="0"
                role="menuitem"
                items={this.props.places} 
                key={item.id}
                onClick={(e)=>{this.props.onItemClick(e, item.id)}}>
                {item.name}</li>
              })}
             </ul>
            {/* </div> */}
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-content .filter:hover,
.dropdown-content .filter:focus,
.dropdown-content ul li:hover,
.dropdown-content ul li:focus {
  background-color: rgb(41, 160, 240);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
 .dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

[This is how it opens on tab press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocTYH.png)

Comment: could you add screenshots to illustrate the behaviour on button-tab? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without running this, I see a couple possibilities here.  First of all, I wouldn't expect tabbing to work because you've given them all the same `tabindex`.  See your `map` function which assigns a hard value of zero to all of you list elements.  `map` has a second param you can pass which is an index.  Use that to generate tabindexes instead.

```
[1, 2, 3].map((x, i) => console.log(i))
```

Second, you are not attaching your tabindexes to anchors.  This creates an a11y problem.  Try adding `menuitem` or maybe `link` aria roles to your list items.  As suggested by MDN, using native anchor elements is probably your best bet.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept my answer.  You can upvote it too if you like. :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix it I used focus:within :

```
.dropdown:focus-within .dropdown-content {
  display: block
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `:focus-within` pseudo selector does not work in IE and the current version of Edge.